# Samsung 7 Application that can record both VoIP and voice calls

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording, voice-recording, google-hangouts

Is there a free application for Samsung 7 that can record both VoIP (WhatsApp, Telegram, Signal, etc.) and voice calls? Is there also an option that while recording that the application will not present any indication? In addition, I would like to know if the app can also record while talking by using Bluetooth?

Comment: What do you mean by "Samsung 7"?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S7